# How to check nexus 5 data has encrypted apart from settings --> encryption status

Tags: android, encryption

i was trying to check whether my nexus 5 has encrypted data successfully or not.
As i am able to pull android application data and it is not encrypted in any means.
my device is rooted and /data is not reflecting as encrypted, yet it is showing encryption success in settings menu.

Comment: Do you mean checking it *programmatically*? If you don't mean that, then you're on the wrong site and I would suggest [android.se].

Comment: Dear friend programmatically it is always giving "inactive".
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
   if (dpm !=null) {Log.e("testcdac","encryption status : " + dpm.getStorageEncryptionStatus());}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you're having trouble with and a detailed description.